# bulk delete in GIT?

Tags: git

If I manually go into windows explorer and delete a bunch of files, is there any way to bulk commit the change?

I believe even after doing a :

git add .

it still tells me I have to do a:

git rm /path/to/file

Which will be a bit annoying if I have tons of files to delete?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`git add -u` will stage all changes to all tracked files, including deletes.

If you have changes that aren't deletes that you don't want to stage you have to do something like:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D -z | xargs -0 git rm --
```

Answer (score 12):

In addition to [Charles Bailey answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786692/bulk-delete-in-git/1786698#1786698) about `git add -u` (or `git add -A` which combines `git add .` with `git add -u`) and automation using `xargs`, I'd like to point out that **`git commit -a`** would *pick file deletions automatically.*